# Check if container / collection exists before running select

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a multi tenant cosmos db. Each tenant has their own container. I am new to cosmos so if any of my terms are in correct please feel free to correct me.

```
var collection = $"{tenant}.expense";
```

I am trying to query data in this collection.

```
var documentRep = new DocumentDbRepository(_storageInfo);
var collection = $"{tenant}.expense";

var sql = $"SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.UserName FROM c WHERE((c.Created >= '{startDate:yyyy-MM-dd}T00:00:00' or c.Modified >= '{startDate:yyyy-MM-dd}T00:00:00') and (c.Created <= '{endDate:yyyy-MM-dd}T23:59:00' or c.Modified <= '{endDate:yyyy-MM-dd}T23:59:00'))) AS x";

var cnt = await documentRep.QueryCountAsync(collection, sql);
```

But if the tenant doesn't actually exist cosmos is returning a 404.  Is there a way to check if the container actually exists in the document rep before running the select?

## DocumentDbRepository.cs

The error is being thrown in this method.  Its getting caught in the genral exception.  not in the DocumentclientException as i would have thought.

Having no results over a period of dates i would expect to result in 0 but thats not the issue here because the tenant being sent is actually invalid for this database it doesn't exist.

```
public class DocumentDbRepository
    {
        private readonly Database _cosmosDatabase;

        public DocumentDbRepository(StorageInfo storageInfo)
        {
            var databaseId = storageInfo.AzureCosmosDb.Collection;
            var endpoint = storageInfo.AzureCosmosDb.Uri;
            var key = storageInfo.AzureCosmosDb.Key;

            var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(endpoint, key);
            _cosmosDatabase = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseId);
        }

        public async Task<int> QueryCountAsync(string collectionId, string sql)
        {
            try
            {
                var container = _cosmosDatabase.GetContainer(collectionId);

                var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sql);

                var queryResultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<int>(queryDefinition);

                var currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();

                return currentResultSet.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
            //NOTE: the error does not catch here
            if (e.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
             {
              return 0;  // 
              }
              else
              {
                  throw;
               }
              }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Error caught here.
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## full error

> Response status code does not indicate success: 404 Substatus: 0 Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found"]}
>   ActivityId: 18569a9-b155-44e1-9248-be86c291b9b5, Request URI: /apps/4867e06-ea60-4691-bcbc-6f423aac702d/services/829b605-5f0c-4728-bbfe-e4696e42f253/partitions/1249694-b944-486b-b3a4-db72b8534085/replicas/32156515793694366s, RequestStats: 
>   RequestStartTime: 2019-10-16T06:44:51.7346321Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-10-16T06:44:51.7346321Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
>   ResponseTime: 2019-10-16T06:44:51.7346321Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.26/apps/4867e06-ea60-4691-bcbc-6f423aac702d/services/0829b605-5f0c-4728-bbfe-e4696e42f253/partitions/1249694-b944-486b-b3a4-db72b8534085/replicas/32156515793694366s, LSN: 40, GlobalCommittedLsn: 40, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 404, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#40, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Read
>   ResponseTime: 2019-10-16T06:44:51.7346321Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.0.0.24/apps/67e06-ea60-4691-bcbc-6f423aac702d/services/0829b605-5f0c-4728-bbfe-e4696e42f253/partitions/d1249694-b944-486b-b3a4-db72b8534085/replicas/32156612013279478s, LSN: 40, GlobalCommittedLsn: 40, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 404, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#40, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Read
>   , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0, Windows/10.0.18362 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.3.0).

## from cosmos

I need to be able to check that tem does not have a .expense container / collection.  Not exactly sure what the term is i am very new to cosmos

[image]

The following does appear to set up a container but the thing is i know for a fact that it doesn't exists.  There must be a way of checking before i call the request.  Or at least catching that the issue is that the collection id is invalid.

```
var container = _cosmosDatabase.GetContainer(collectionId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the following methods if you are using the SDK

[`DocumentClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdatabaseifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet)
[`DocumentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentcollectionifnotexistsasync?view=azure-dotnet)

EDIT

you can take all Container informations in a list, by query with (and without) condition.

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("yourEndPointUrl"), "yourAuthKey");
var list = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

then you can verify if it exists or not, there is no direct method available

You can get collections with the following method,

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey);

Database database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery("SELECT * FROM d WHERE d.id = \"[YOUR_DATABASE_ID]\"").AsEnumerable().First();

List<DocumentCollection> collections = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery((String)database.SelfLink).ToList();
```

Comment: I dont actually want to create anything. I just want to know if its there or not.  I am not allowed to write to this database.

Comment: Unfortunately that appears to only list databases not the containers / collections with in it.

Comment: The select returns sequence contains no elements.  I think i see what you are trying to do.

Comment: try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-collections

Comment: var doc = (await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(collUrl)).Resource; <-- that crashes and throws a DocumentClientException with a status code of NotFound.   Which is good enough for me to be able to catch the error.   Thanks for your help